# Should you use absolute paths to system binaries in scripts

Tags: linux, scripting

When writing scripts on linux, are there any guidelines on whether to use absolute paths or not when calling system binaries? For example, I'm working on an installer and there are a bunch of copies, permission changes, service changes etc. Initially I had them as all absolute but when I checked one of the packages I generated with Lintain, it was not happy with absolute paths.

1) Should I be doing /bin/cp, /usr/sbin/useradd or cp, useradd and assume the $PATH will be setup correctly (what if it had been compromised?)

Looking through the FSSTND and FHS standards they do list some specific binaries and where they should be installed but there are many others (such as systemctl) that could be in different locations depending on distribution.

2) Is there a way to create a localized search path in the script e.g. not use $PATH but maybe something like `TRUST_PATH=/bin;/usr/bin;/usr/sbin;/sbin` and then only have these as the search path in the script? (I'm assuming that I can't verify the legitimacy of the binaries in these paths)

Comment: You could just `unset $PATH` (if SHELL is bash) and redefine it.

Comment: You might want to use `mycopy=\`type cp 2>/dev/null | sed 's/^.*\ //'\`` (and check if the result is empty) in bash (see `help type`).

Comment: You can experiment with this from the cli for instance by doing: `( PATH=$HOME/bin type cp )`. If I do this I get: `bash: type: cp: not found` because there is no `cp` in `$HOME/bin`. The parenthesis indicate: run the enclosed commands in their own shell.  This way you can more readily experiment from the cli, without having to create or edit a script each time, and without modifying variables (like PATH!) in the current shell.

Comment: Another example: `( PATH=$HOME/bin mycopy=type cp 2>/dev/null | /bin/sed 's/^.*\ //'; echo $mycopy )`.  `type cp` returns an empty string here (cp not in the specified PATH). Also note I am specifying a complete path for sed.

Comment: Instead of the sed command above, you can use `echo ${V##*\ }`, for instance: `( mycopy=\`type cp 2>/dev/null\` ; echo ${mycopy##*\ } )`.

Comment: But should I use an absolute path? Is it the 'done' thing or am I seeing a problem that doesn't exist?

Comment: You can use an absolute path, but there are many utilities that a UNIX-like system must have to be conformant to e.g. the POSIX spec.
May I direct you attention to this: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/ .

Comment: In general this means that for a great number of 'utility' programs, you can assume that a) it is installed somewhere in PATH but even
more specific b) that it is installed in a standard place, like for instance /bin/sh (note that /bin/sh doesn't necessarily equate to /bin/bash), /bin/cp, etc. See the link.

Comment: This implies that the path location of e.g. cp or sh can be assumed to be in the PATH env.variable. And in turn all of the above imply that in scripts, you can just refer to plain 'cp' etc.  Again, see the URL just provided for some common standards. Things become difficult for software that transcends the name 'utility', e.g. python. Note its absence in the 'utilities' list. For such a program `type <program>` may be used to get its path.

Comment: On the aforementioned URL, click on 'Shell & Utilities' in the upper left, and then click on 'Utilities' in the lower left pane. You'll then be presented with a list of standard utilities.

Comment: Maybe start here: https://publications.opengroup.org/standards/unix